# sshfs: how to mount a drive on a SSH double hop with different authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, sshfs

I have the following which works to get me to the end server:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p ServerA" hackJJ@localhost-p 2222
```

The basic, very basic layout:

```
Me -> ServerA -> ServerB (localhost)
```

`ServerA` uses a key and logs me straight in. `ServerB` needs a password.

My question is how can I then mount a drive from `ServerB` to `Me`? I have tried the following but connection gets reset and debugging it gives `invalid quotes`

```
sshfs hackJJ@localhost :/remote/path /local/path -o ssh_command='ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p ServerA" -p 2222'
```

Any ideas? My device is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the parameters in your `~/.ssh/config` instead:

```
Host ServerB
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ServerA
    Hostname localhost
    Port 2222
    HostkeyAlias ServerB
    User hackJJ
```

This will match connections made to "ServerB", e.g. `sshfs ServerB:/foo`.

With recent OpenSSH this type of ProxyCommand can be replaced with **`ProxyJump ServerA`** (which also has the command-line option `-J ServerA` if you really want to keep using `ssh_command=`).

It sounds like the connection is also being made through a second tunnel from ServerA – in that case you might even be able to use `ProxyJump ServerA,ServerC` instead of the localhost:2222 thing. (This would need the local client to have credentials for all hops.)